# Redirect to browsed url after login(authentication)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have developed a module which authorizes the roles from the database dynamically. Now, what i want is,when a user comes and browses different actionmethod without logging in, I am able to redirect the user to the login page. As soon as the user logs in, he should be redirected to the actionmethod/view which he was trying to access without login. The following is the code which i am using to extract the URL browsed without logging in. I also have a key defined in my web.config as `serverURL` which gives me initial url like `localhost`. How to i make the below returnurl remembered and redirect the user to the desired actionmethod/view after logging in.

```
returnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;


public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public string Feature { get; set; }
        public string returnUrl { get; set; }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            //var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            //if (!isAuthorized)
            //{
            //    return false;
            //}

            if (httpContext != null && httpContext.Session != null && httpContext.Session["Role"] != null)
            {
                string userRoles = UserBL.ValidateUsersRoleFeature(httpContext.Session["Role"].ToString(), Feature);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userRoles))
                {
                    if (userRoles.IndexOf(httpContext.Session["Role"].ToString()) >= 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }


        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;

            if (session.IsNewSession || session["Email"] == null)
            {
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    // For AJAX requests, return result as a simple string, 
                    // and inform calling JavaScript code that a user should be redirected.
                    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
                    result.ContentType = "text/html";
                    result.Data = "SessionTimeout";
                    filterContext.Result = result;

                    //$.ajax({
                    //    type: "POST",
                    //    url: "controller/action",
                    //    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    //    dataType: "json",
                    //    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    //    async: true,
                    //    complete: function (xhr, status) {
                    //            if (xhr.responseJSON == CONST_SESSIONTIMEOUT) {
                    //                RedirectToLogin(true);
                    //                return false;
                    //            }
                    //            if (status == 'error' || !xhr.responseText) {
                    //                alert(xhr.statusText);
                    //            }
                    //        }
                    //    });
                    //}
                }
                else
                {
                    // For round-trip requests,
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new RouteValueDictionary { { "Controller", "User" }, { "Action", "Login" } });

                    returnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;

                }
            }
            else
                base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new RouteValueDictionary(
                            new
                            {
                                controller = "Base",
                                action = "PageNotAccessible"
                            })
                        );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In attribute return the url on which user was in routes:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                             new RouteValueDictionary 
                                  { 
                                     { "Controller", "User" }, 
                                     { "Action", "Login" },
                                     {"returnUrl",HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl} 
                                  });
```

and in your action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public virtual ActionResult Login()
{
   ViewBag.returnUrl = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"];
   return View();
}
```

In View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Login","User",new{returnUrl = ViewBag.returnUrl},FormMethod.Post))
{
 <input type="submit" value="Login" />
}
```

and in Post Action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Login(User model, string returnUrl)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      // check if login successful redirect to url from where user came
      if(LoginSucessful)
        return Redirect(returnUrl); // will be redirected to url from where user came to login 

   return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your html page, create a hidden tag:

```
<div id="HiddenURL" class="hidden"></div>
```

the moment the user access a certain page, use Javascript to bind the url the user came from in a hidden value in you web page:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
 { 
$('#HiddenURL').text(window.location.href.toLowerCase());

...
}
```

In your asp.net page assign to action, the url taken from div text:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new RouteValueDictionary(
                            new
                            {
                                controller = "Base",
                                action = HiddenURL.Value
                            })
                        );
        }
```